# docker ps -a only displaying containers from past 24 hours

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

It is my understanding that `docker ps -a` should display all containers; however, on my ec2 instance it is only displaying containers that were started within the past 24 hours.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Please let me know if there is any information that would be helpful for me to share regarding my docker or ec2 configs.

Comment: did you reboot your ec2 instance 24 hours back. Due to that you maybe getting only containers for past 24 hours.

Comment: @YugSingh I thought that as well, but running `last reboot` on the ec2 instance shows the last reboot was 3 days ago, and hundreds of containers have started and completed between 1 and 3 days

Comment: Are you using Kubernetes or some other tools that maybe performs garbage collection?